# html5 player does not show in IE 11 when src is base 64 string

Tags: html, video

The page referred to is here: http://www.rtbaileyphd.com/src/testjunk/HTML5VideoProblem.out.html
There should be 2 HTML5 video players showing there.  Both play the same video, but for the first one the src file has been base 64 encoded and embedded into the HTML.  So the source is specified like src="data:video/mp4;base64,AAA...".  This approach is mandatory for my application.  In the 2nd video the standard approach of using src="http://..." is used.  If you view this page in Chrome, Firefox, or Opera both players show.  However, for IE 11 the 1st video player will not show unless you hover the mouse over where it is supposed to be.  You can get the video to play if you do that.  The problem is resolved if the autoplay option is added, but I do not want the videos to automatically play.  Is there a way to put an image of a player underneath the actual, invisible player?  I tried the poster attribute, but the poster image does not show either.

Answer (score 0):

After posting, the answer came to me.  Since the video will show if autoplay is turned on, just add autoplay to the video tag, and since I have a Javascript page initialization function anyway, also add Javascript to that to pause all videos just after the page is first shown.  See [Pause Multiple HTML5 Videos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676188/pause-multiple-html5-videos)
for the Javascript.